# MySQL - why LEFT JOIN and NULL condition on NON-NULL column are returning all the rows

Tags: mysql, join, null, left-join

The MySQL query is :

```
     SELECT 
     p1.id,p1.name, p1.category_id, p1.price AS p1_price, p2.price as p2_price 
     FROM
     products p1 
     LEFT JOIN products p2 
     ON p1.category_id=p2.category_id AND  
     p1.price<p2.price AND p2.price IS NULL
```

The `products` table  is shown in the following screenshot :

[image]

And the result the query produces is in the following screenshot :

[image]

The result actually shows the table as it is with just a column (i.e. `p2_price`) with all `NULL` values.

But the condition `AND p2.price IS NULL` in the `ON` condition seems to be never true as no row
in the table `p2` has `NULL` value in the `price` column. So how is the result produced ?

**EDIT:** this question never uses the term `INNER JOIN` and is therefore not any duplicate of any question regarding `INNER JOIN`.

**EDIT2:** This question is about MySQL, so it cannot be termed as duplicate of any question of other language i,e. SQL .

Comment: Predicate `p2.price IS NULL` is applied to the `LEFT JOIN` operation, i.e. to the rows returned by the left-joined table, `products p2` in this case. The predicate has no effect on the records returned from `products p1` table.

Comment: A LEFT JOIN cannot be used to limit the returned rows. If you want to return only some of the rows based on a JOIN condition, use an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097).

Comment: Read a definition of left join: it returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. What reference are you using? What do you get when you apply its definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join) Beware of all the poor answers there. *The most upvoted answer is very poor.* See my many comments & also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46091641/3404097).

Comment: @philipxy, The OP is about MySQL whereas the question you pointed to is about SQL.

Comment: MySQL is a version of SQL, and for this question an "SQL" answer is a MySQL answer, and anyway there are zillions of other answers, which you will discover if you search, which should be done before asking. You should also have read a definition, tried to apply it, referenced it here, and shown your efforts here, as I also already commented. Also, the *answers* (that are not poor) to the duplicate question answer your question. Please read [ask], the downvote arrow mouseover text, and hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158621/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-philipxy).

Comment: @philipxy, the question arose out of a vague concept about `LEFT JOIN` which the asker could not identify himself. Question can be marked as duplicate only when same question has been asked again which obviously is not the case here. Lots of questions are in SO that stem from same problem and can be solved with a clear concept about the issue but those cannot be marked as duplicate as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `on p1.category_id = p2.category_id and p1.price < p2.price and p2.price is null` is always false. Therefore the resulting *left* join is each row from products (`p1`) filled up with `NULL` values for the products (`p2`) columns, e.g.

> 1, 'LG P880 4X HD', 336, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
>   2, 'Google Nexus 4', 299, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
>   ...
>   12, 'Abercrombie Lake Arnold Shirt', 60, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL

Answer (score 3):

You are using a LEFT JOIN, which means p1 will always keep its values, whereas p2 is only non-NULL when the JOIN conditions apply

Maybe you want to move some of the conditions to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 
p1.id,p1.name, p1.category_id, p1.price AS p1_price, p2.price as p2_price 
FROM
products p1 
LEFT JOIN products p2 ON p1.category_id=p2.category_id AND p1.price<p2.price
WHERE p2.price IS NULL
```

In cases like these it's important to distinguish between the JOIN ON conditions and the WHERE conditions. WHERE conditions apply to the entire result set.

Comment: Actually the `p2.price IS NULL` was in `WHERE` clause but I just want to inspect the result if it is inside the `ON` condition. " whereas p2 is only non-NULL when the JOIN conditions apply " -what  do you mean  ?

Comment: It's the very basics of what a [LEFT JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) does. A left join always returns all columns from the original table (p1). From the dependent table (p2) it only returns the actual data if the JOIN conditions are True, otherwise the fields are set to NULL.

Comment: 'whereas p2 is only non-NULL when the JOIN conditions apply' - I think you meant : when all the JOIN conditions are fulfilled, right ?

Comment: JOIN conditions apply === all the JOIN conditions are fulfilled - correct.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you must know for `LEFT JOIN`.

**The first:**

`ON` clause builds only the link between two tables. If left table doesn't match this link, informations about this table will return NULL.

If you want to cut these rows, you must move your conditions in `WHERE` clause

**The second:**

NULL comparing: Only if you use `IS NULL / IS NOT NULL` you can correctly process a condition with `NULL`. If you compare two fields (for example p1.price and p2.price) if one of them is null you haven't `TRUE` but `UNKNOWN`

Comment: When the `ON` condition is applied to the `LEFT JOIN` , I get many rows. Does this mean  that for all the rows in result, `p2.price` is `NULL` ?

Comment: Yes, because you have told: give me the rows from table left where p1.category_id=p2.category_id AND  
     p1.price<p2.price AND p2.price IS NULL (If this isn't true DBMS returns NULL)